# Do app makers need to pay royalties if their software generates PDFs?

Tags: licensing, intellectual-property

I'm building a (for-pay) web/mobile app that will generate PDF reports for customers. Do I need to pay someone a royalty? Who? How much and what are the terms?

Surprisingly, the best info I was able to find was from the [PDF wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) where it simply lists PDF as an "Open" format. But no mention of royalties, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Adobe grants every individual and organization in the
>   world the royalty-free right, under all Essential Claims that Adobe
>   owns, to make, have made, use, sell, import and distribute Compliant
>   Implementations. If a licensee brings (or participates directly or
>   indirectly in the bringing of) a lawsuit or similar action against any
>   other party claiming that a Compliant Implementation infringes an
>   Essential Claim, Adobe may revoke the rights granted above to such
>   licensee. Upon such revocation, such rights will be deemed to have
>   never been granted.

https://www.adobe.com/pdf/pdfs/ISO32000-1PublicPatentLicense.pdf

Comment: So, in layman terms, "it is free, but if you piss me you are going to thoroughly regret it"?